# Automatic binding of Model Driven inherited classes data members with UI form attributes in Struts 2

Tags: jsp, struts2, model-driven

1. I have a Model class as below:

   ```
   class MYModel { 
     List<String> companyName;
   }
   ```
2. I have an Action say:

   ```
   class MyAction extends ActionSupport implements ModelDriven<MYModel>
   {
      MyModel objModel=new MyModel();

     // getters n setters for "objModel"
   }
   ```
3. Now, i have input form say, Input.jsp:

   ```
   <form ...>
   <div>
     <input type="text" name="companyName" id="id1">
   </div>
   <div>
     <input type="text"  name="companyName" id="id2">
   </div>
   ```
4. Let, i have output form say, Output.jsp:

   ```
   <div>
     <input type="text" name="companyName" id="id3">
   </div>
   <div>
     <input type="text" name="companyName" id="id4">
   </div>
   ```

The problem is I want to directly map (not using javascript or jquery) to output.jsp. That is: if I type in 4 in `textfield(with id=1)`, then textfied with `id=3`  should automatically set the value 4. Remember, the names of text field has to be the same.

Comment: The getters/setters should go inside the model when using ModelDriven. Then what you describe is pretty typical behavior however for output you'll use an iterator (see struts2 tag reference documentation in iterator tag). I don't see anything in your question that I would call automatic binding it seems pretty manual to me (at least no more automatic than usual in struts2, which of course does do work for us but to call it "automatic" I would expect a requirement that goes beyond typical).

Comment: Your question is very vague. Could you explain more what are you trying to do.

Comment: I got to use struts tags in input.jsp and output.jsp for "Dynamic binding" because struts tags are understood by server and are automatically mapped to Model. There is no way out for simple html tags used for dynamic binding.